# Extending/implementing force:slds at component level

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, slds

With Lightning most of my use case has been creating a component and adding it to the Lightning app builder page. I use  just to preview my component behavior from developer console.

Having said this I see developers/salesforce docs load the SLDS as static resource and reference it in components using `ltng:require`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apps_slds.htm

http://www.sfdcmonkey.com/2016/12/26/use-lightning-design-system-framework/

The major disadvantage I see with this method is getting struck to a specific version and constantly having to update the slds version in the static resource to the latest version from the server.
Is there any way I can extend/ implement the force:slds as an interface at a component level?

For the sake of argument if I use only lightning:XXXX components in my code, I will inherit lightning styling by default but this is not possible all the time. When using ui:XXX and custom html components I will have to use the SLDS as a static resource to apply styling on my non lightning:XXXX components.

Am I missing something basic (or) is loading SLDS as a static resource the only way to use SLDS at a component level?

Comment: You don’t need to load anything. The slds just works by default in lightning. Am I misunderstanding your question? I don’t even use the extends:slds

Comment: @Eric can you post that as an answer, I always thought slds has to be included through ltng:require to apply the style to in a custom component.  I missed the basic concept that SLDS is part of lightning and <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">Refresh</button> would resolve with lightning styles applied because as you said slds is part of lightning.

Comment: Done. Not sure what the use case is for extending force:slds is though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to load anything. The slds just works by default in lightning

I may be missing some use cases though as I am not sure why there is documentation stating you should extend force:slds when I have never needed to.....

Comment: My guess is Including the force:slds as static resource may have been relevant when exposing component in a vf page prior to winter 18 , but with lightstylesheets= true / apex:slds option at the apex:page level we may no more need slds as static resource

Comment: @Rao - Yea, but the extends="force:slds" is only relevant to the lightning component so not sure what its purpose is now yet the winter 18 documentation still includes it

Comment: In a application perspective, you still need the extends=force:slds in your aura:application and when previewing the component from the developer console right?

Comment: @Rao - not sure. I have never had to use it. Then again I don't use dev console at all so maybe. I have several lightning applications but none of them use the force:slds and they work just fine since lightning automatically includes the styles

Comment: When you include <c:component> inside aura:application from dev console my understanding is the aura:application works like a stand alone app/ a seperate container where the page does not have context of lightning stylesheets, hence we need to extend force:slds to apply the lightning style sheets

Comment: Also one major advantage i see embedding component inside  aura:application is getting to see real time changes to the component when i update the component. When you embed the component inside the page caching is a pain in the rear to deal with, caching within lightning makes it hard to see the updates to the component for which i use the aura: application approach

Comment: Has anyone tried the sample code from the W18 release notes that illustrate scenarios requiring it? For example: Usage Considerations
When using lightning:icon in a standalone app, extend force:slds to resolve the icon resources correctly.
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
<lightning:icon iconName="utility:error" variant="error"/>
</aura:application>